# How to add context menu for ListBox(SUI) or TreeView(SUI) in indesign javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, listbox, contextmenu, adobe-indesign

collegues

I'm developing indesign plugin on javascript.
In plugin exist window, on it placed ListBox component.
How I can add context menu to my ListBox component?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are developing C++ plugin or ScriptUI window ?

Comment: I'm devesloping in ScriptUI.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like a contextual menu but you could fake one by creating a new window on click with no borders and every other fancy stuffs (mouseover…). Not easy but somehow achievable. Have you considered extensions ?

Comment: It's interresting idea. I going implent it. Thanks))

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is an approach. I think it's a good starting point:

```js
//A sugar to color groups
var o = {
 paintItem:function(o,c){
   var r = (c && c.r) || Math.round ( Math.random()*10 )/10;
   var g  = (c && c.g) || Math.round ( Math.random()*10 )/10;
   var b = (c && c.b) || Math.round ( Math.random()*10 )/10;
   var a = (c && c.a) || 1;
   o.graphics.backgroundColor = o.graphics.newBrush(o.graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR,[r,g,b], a);
  },
}

//Main routine
var main = function() {
 
 var w = new Window( "dialog", "testingRightClickMenu" ),
 g = w.add('group'),
 btn = g.add('button', undefined, "Cancel" );
 
 //Calling our rightClickMenu "factory"
 var rightClickMenu = rightClickWindow(w);
 rightClickMenu.visible = false;
 rightClickMenu.alignment = ["left","top"] ;
 
 //Mouse click events handler
 var handler = function(evt) {
  
  var screenX = evt.screenX;
  var screenY = evt.screenY;
  var fb = w.bounds;
  var x = screenX- fb[0]+2;
  var y = screenY- fb[1]+2;
  
  //If button click is actually a right click event
  if ( evt.button==2 ) {
   
   //Displaying the right click menu to position x,y
   rightClickMenu.visible = true;
   rightClickMenu.location = [x,y];
  }
 }

 //Setting some UI properties
 w.orientation = 'stack';
 w.preferredSize = [500, 300];
 g.alignment = ["fill","fill"];
 
 //adding mouse click listener
 w.addEventListener ("click", handler, true);
 
 //HACK
 //adding listeners to sub level elements ended with bad behaviors
 //Instead we look at mouse pointer location
 //and hide right click menu if needed
 w.addEventListener ( "mouseout", function(evt) {
  var x1 = rightClickMenu.location[0];
  var x2 = x1+rightClickMenu.size.width;
  var y1 = rightClickMenu.location[1];
  var y2 = y1+rightClickMenu.size.height;
  if ( !rightClickMenu.visible ) return;
  var mouseX = evt.screenX-w.bounds[0];
  var mouseY = evt.screenY-w.bounds[1];
  
  //basicallly checking if the pointer is somewhere else but over the right click menu
  if ( mouseX<x1 
  ||
  mouseX > x2
  ||
  mouseY < y1
  ||
  mouseY > y2 ) rightClickMenu.hide();
  
 });
 w.show();
}

//Some color settings
var colors = {
 grey : {r:240/255,g:240/255,b:240/255},
 blue: {r:79/255,g:157/255,b:251/255},
 transparent:{r:1,g:1,b:1, a:0},
}

//Our pseudo factory for the right click menu
var rightClickWindow = function(p) {

 //Our pseudo "factory" for teh menu Items
 var getMenuItem = function(p, label){
  var menuItem = p.add('group'),
  menuLabel = menuItem.add('statictext', undefined, label );
  menuItem.alignment = "fill";
  
  //Dealing with mouse events
  menuItem.addEventListener ( "mouseover", function() {
   o.paintItem ( menuItem, colors.blue );
   menuLabel.graphics.foregroundColor = menuLabel.graphics.newPen (menuLabel.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 1, 1], 1);
  });
  menuItem.addEventListener ( "mouseout", function() {
   o.paintItem ( menuItem, colors.grey);
   menuLabel.graphics.foregroundColor = menuLabel.graphics.newPen (menuLabel.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [0, 0, 0], 1);
  });
  menuItem.addEventListener ( "mousedown", function() {
   rightClickMenu.hide();
   alert("You chose "+label );
  });
  o.paintItem ( menuItem, colors.grey);
  return menuItem;
 }

 //menu construction
 var rightClickMenu = p.add('group'),
 menuItem1 = getMenuItem(rightClickMenu, "MenuItem A" );
 menuItem2 = getMenuItem(rightClickMenu, "MenuItem B" );
 menuItem3 = getMenuItem(rightClickMenu, "MenuItem C" );
 rightClickMenu.maximumSize = [100,150];
 
 //Menu UI properties
 rightClickMenu.orientation = "column";
 rightClickMenu.alignment = "fill";
 rightClickMenu.alignChildren = ["fill", "top"];
 rightClickMenu.margins = 5;
 o.paintItem ( rightClickMenu,  colors.grey );
 

 return rightClickMenu;
}

//Running UI
try {
 main();
}
catch(err) {
 alert( err.line+"//"+err.message );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!!
Many thanks, unfortunately I can't increase your. But, Thank you very much!

Comment: By curiosity, why so ?

Comment: Sorry)) I lost word "rate".
true sentense is " Many thanks, unfortunately I can't increase your rate. ".
Because I'm paticular visit to this site.

Comment: Oh, about upvoting ? Don't really care about that. I suggest solutions when I think they can help. I thought you meant you couldn't take advantage of the solution I provided hence my question ;)

Comment: Take a look at : https://github.com/indiscripts/extendscript/tree/master/scriptui